# Why is the sizeof() returning 4 for this class with 2 bytes

Tags: c++, arduino-esp8266

When I print a sizeof(SenseNode) of the class defined below, 4 is returned. I was expecting it to be 2, because of the 2 uint8_t private members.
What i using the other 2 bytes?

```
enum NodeType { unknown = 255, temperature=0, button=1, text=2, page=3, dualstate=4, slider=5, alarmHandler=6, clock=7, gps=8,
                         yawpitchroll = 9, gsm = 10, alert = 11 };

class SenseNode {
  public:
    SenseNode(uint8_t id) : SenseNode(id, NodeType::unknown) {};
    SenseNode(uint8_t id, NodeType type) : id(id), nodeType(type) {};
    virtual ~SenseNode() = default;

    // Dispatcher of notifyObserver
    virtual void notifyObserver2(SenseObserver* observer);

    /* Accessor for property Id */
    uint8_t getId() { return id; }
    NodeType getNodeType() { return nodeType; }
  private:
    uint8_t id = 0;
    uint8_t nodeType = NodeType::unknown;
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Size of C++ classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281932/size-of-c-classes)

Comment: virtuals pointers, remeber!!! BTW hard to imagine transmit via some protocol  whole virtual objects

Comment: I'd expect it to be at least 8.

Comment: What is `sizeof(void*)` on your platform?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat He's on arduino so 2

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `SenseNode` class is polymorphic because your have a virtual function. Compiler adds pointer to vtable and as a result the size of class depends on platform. In your case the size of pointer is 2 and we have 2 + 1 + 1 = 4. You can read about this topic [here](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/size_of_class_object.html) and [here](http://joeyates.info/2010/05/12/object-representation-in-c/).